# how do i group rows by an id row in group_concat into one row string?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this

```
|  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |
|  a     |  1     |  g1    |
|  b     |  2     |  g1    |
|  c     |  3     |  g1    |
|  d     |  4     |  g2    |
|  e     |  5     |  g2    |
|  f     |  6     |  g2    |
```

i want to select them group by **`col3 column`** to get this result

```
g1: a1, b2, c3-g2: d4, e5, f6
```

i used

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(col3,":",GROUP_CONCAT(col1, col2))
FROM table
GROUP BY col3
```

to get rows like this

```
--------------
g1:a1,b2,c3
--------------
g2:d4,e5,f6
--------------
```

but i want to merge them into one string separated by dashes like this

```
g1:a1,b2,c3-g2:d4,e5,f6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, you can use another `GROUP_CONCAT`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cEbW3ZoQBRpun3Pt5g3h3v/4).

```
select
  GROUP_CONCAT(ncol separator '-') as merged_rows
from
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT(col3,":",GROUP_CONCAT(col1, col2)) as ncol
  FROM table
  GROUP BY col3
) val
```

Output:

```
| merged_rows             |
| ----------------------- |
| g1:a1,b2,c3-g2:d4,e5,f6 |
```

Comment: is this the only way to do it?

Comment: @JoeDoe cannot think of any other option but this would be the ideal way to achieve your output. :)

Comment: @JoeDoe . . . This is the simplest way to do this.  I can imagine other methods, but this is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a subquery.  But the logic is rather complicated -- using json functions, window functions, and fixing up strings:

```
select col3, group_concat(col1),
       replace(replace(replace(json_unquote(json_arrayagg(concat(col3, ':', group_concat(col1))) over (order by col3)),
                               '["', ''
                              ), '"]', ''
                      ), '", "', '-'
              )
from t
group by col3
order by col3 desc
limit 1;
```

JSON is needed in order to "aggregate" the strings using a window function, to avoid the subquery.  The logic would be a bit simpler if MySQL supported `group_concat()` (or the standard `listagg()`) as a window function.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae06501984e49aa4394f8fc80c3ea1a0) is a db<>fiddle.

For instance, [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e7aeab5693d4c7d1f1e05016ee4e67e) is what the logic looks like in Postgres, which does support string aggregation as a window function.